# chaining mapreduce jobs in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop. My task is to find an employee who has max salary.
In my firstmap class I split the word and put the key and value like this -

```
outputcollector.collect("salary",salary);
```

In my reducer I found the maximum salary and had set the output like this

```
outputcollector.collect("max salary",maxsalary);
```

Now I want to use the output from this reducer in another mapper.
I have constructed a chain like this

```
JobConf mapAConf = new JobConf(false);
        ChainMapper.addMapper(conf, mymap.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true, mapAConf); 

JobConf reduceConf = new JobConf(false);
        ChainReducer.setReducer(conf, myreduce.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true, reduceConf);

JobConf mapCConf = new JobConf(false);
       ChainReducer.addMapper(conf, LastMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true, mapCConf);
```

But the reducer is not getting executed. Any help on this?

Comment: Any error stacktraces you have? Thanks!

Comment: nope no error..but reducer is not executing

Answer (score 0):

You need to create & set the same JobConf for both mapper & reducer for a single Map/Reduce Job.